# How to get information from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a database named superstore and 4 tables. [image]

```
-- Q5: Pull all the order details of Product 
-- (ID: 657768) got sold at a discount rate of 0.06
SELECT * FROM superstore.orders JOIN 
superstore.product  ON 
superstore.orders.ProductID=superstore.product.ProductID 
WHERE 
superstore.product.ProductID='657768' AND Discount='0.06';
```

This returns me an empty record. How can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need single quote around numeric fields - but mysql should do an implicit conversion anyway. Try removing the join to see if you get anything back from orders alone and then add a left join to product to see if null is retruned from product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product p
JOIN Orders o ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE 
   p.ProductID = '657768' AND 
   Discount = 0.06;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to use column names in SELECT query instead of "*" as it becomes slow if you have tables with thousands of records.

```
SELECT 
    p.ProductID,p.ProductName,p.ProductCategory,p.ProductSubCategory,
    p.ProductContainer,p.ProductBaseMargin 
    FROM Product p
    JOIN Orders o ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
    WHERE p.ProductID = '657768' AND o.Discount=0.06
```